# Find count of rows that don't contain a particular date?

Tags: sql

I am trying to work out the number of people that DID NOT have a video on loan on a specific day, say 25-OCT-13.  I have a **dateout** and **datein** field but for the life of me can't work out what steps to take to continue because I don't have a range to work with, only the specific date.

I thought if I could find out how many items were out on that day then I can NOT the query but then i'm still stuck with the original problem.

What is the simplest method to check this?

I'm using SQL developer 
The table consists of, ItemNo, CardNo, DateOut, DateIn.

I was thinking of a BETWEEN but AFAIK that is only for a range and using the same date doesn't seem to work. I don't know enough about how dates work TBH.

The end result would ideally be a count of all the unique CardNo that do not have an ItemNo out on a specific date.

Comment: Also, what is the tables scheme?

Comment: Need more description of your issue, don't understand what you really want to get out from your query, provide schema and expected result, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the number of people who did not have a video on loan on a particular date, you need to know how many people have a card, and how many people did have a video on loan on the particular date.

You seem to have two tables:

- CardHolder: CardNo, ...
- LoanItem: CardNo, ItemNo, DateIn, DateOut, ...

So, the number of cardholders is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CardHolder
```

The number of people with one or more items on loan on the 25th October 2013 is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CardNo)
  FROM LoanItem
 WHERE DATE '2013-10-25' BETWEEN DateOut AND DateIn
```

So, you need:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CardHolder) -
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CardNo)
          FROM LoanItem
         WHERE DATE '2013-10-25' BETWEEN DateOut AND DateIn
       )
```

You might need to provide a table to SELECT from — it depends on your DBMS.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CardHolder) -
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CardNo)
          FROM LoanItem
         WHERE DATE '2013-10-25' BETWEEN DateOut AND DateIn
       )
  FROM Dual;
```

Or any other 1-row table.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  This gives me something I can work with to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Just basing on guessing what you may need, certainly I don't fully understand your question.

```
    select count(distinct people) 
    from tableName 
    where '25-OCT-2013' not between DateOut and DateIN
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your time. I'll try give more info in the future.